# C++ How to create two seperate objects that display random numbers 10 times?

Tags: c++, class, random, numbers, generator

The program I am trying to write is to create two objects to display random numbers between 1000-9000 and 100-900 respectively.

I am trying to write my first C++ program that uses classes and multiple files but have issues. I get errors in the for loop in main() function; it says expected primary-expression before 'R' and '<<' for the second for loop too, with 'r'.

Any help or guidance is appreciated :)

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Random.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  srand(time(0));


  for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  {
      cout << RandomNum four(1000,9000); << endl;
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  {
      cout << RandomNum three(100,900); << endl;
  }
}
```

Random.h:

```
#ifndef RANDOM_H
#define RANDOM_H

class RandomNum
{
    public:
        RandomNum(int ix, int iy);
        int operator ()();
        int operator ()(int ny);
        int operator ()(int nx, int ny);

        int x,y;
};

#endif
```

randomNum.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "randomInt.h"
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

RandomInt::RandomInt(int ix, int iy):x(ix), y(iy)
{}

int RandomInt::operator()()
{
    return x + rand() % (y - x + 1);
}

int RandomInt::operator()(int ny)
{
    return x + rand() % (ny - x + 1);
}

int RandomInt::operator()(int nx, int ny)
{
    return nx + rand() % (ny - nx + 1);
}
```

Comment: The syntax error has nothing to do with anything in the title. Read it again (closely) and fix it. What is `RandomNum four(1000,9000)` *supposed* to do? In what *context*?

Comment: Thank you for input does that make more sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### THE PROBLEM

You cannot declare a variable in the middle of an expression, and the following is all sort of wrong.

```
cout << RandomNum four(1000,9000); << endl;
```

```
cout << RandomNum three(100,900); << endl;
```

---

#### THE SOLUTION

Change the contents of *main* to first declare `four` and `three` to be instances of type `RandomNum` and initialize them as you want, then later call their `operator()` inside the *cout-expressions*.

```
RandomNum four (1000,9000); // declaration of `four`
RandomNum three (100, 900); // declaration of `three`
```

```
cout << four () << endl;
```

```
cout << three () << endl;
```

Comment: I understand now :). To create 10 for each I include the for loop to iterate to 10.

Comment: Just for completeness, you can actually create the object "inline", but it's typically not recommended, since your code is harder to read and you're creating and throwing away the object rather then possibly reusing it later (not that bad since your class is rather light here): `cout << RandomNum(1000, 9000)() << endl;` Note the additional brackets and omission of an actual name.